# indexerror in python with beaglebone black

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

```
y[i] = ADC.read("P9_40")
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

the code:

```
i = 1
x = []*1000
y = []*1000
for i in range(1000): 
        y[i] = ADC.read("P9_40") # adc input pin
        x[i] = (int)(y*2147483648) # conversion of float to int
```

this code is read data from analogue pin of beaglebone black and store the result in array

Comment: How is "ADC" defined?

Answer (score 0):

In python you can't call a uncreated index of a list

```
x = []*1000 #creates only one empty list not 1000 list of list
y = []*1000 #like wise here
```

It should rather be like this

```
x = [[] for i in range(1000)]
y = [[] for i in range(1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a 1000 element list by doing:

```
x = [] * 1000
y = [] * 1000
```

What you should do is create it with `None` values:

```
x = [None] * 1000
y = [None] * 1000
```

and then you can overwrite those `None` in your loop. `None` is better than
any integer value (like `0`) that might come out of `ADC.read()`, as you can
check if the whole list is updated afterwards.